# How to pick up a bag in Payday 1?

Tags: payday-the-heist

Do I have to drop it only once and I can't pick it up, or can I? How?

I am using the PC version.

Comment: Do you mean ammo/health bags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot pick up ammo/health bags once you put them down. You have to choose a good spot. Coordinate and talk with your teammates so that you don't put it in a bad spot.